# Difference between 想象 and 想像

Tags: characters

What's the difference between *想象* and *想像*? Is one more correct than the other one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More correct? Isn't that it bit like saying more unique?

想象：think of an elephant ：）：）
想像：think of a picture ：）：）
像：elephant man ?? 亻 + （大）象 ：）：）

想像 has more a meaning of 'want (to be) like

In this sentence you would not use 想像, according to my quick survey：

事实与想象恰恰相反。
Reality and fancy are exactly opposite.

And in this sentence, you would not use 想象：

我想像她一样。
I want to be like her.

Therefore they are not always interchangeable.

My advice: look up a few sentences with both words, then substitute 想像 for 想象 and vice versa. Consult a Chinese friend, to see if he or she accepts the substitution.

Comment: Note: '想' and '像'  in '我想像她一样' is verb 'want' and 'to like' not a compound word. It has nothing to do with "想像" (imagine)

Answer (score 3):

*规范* dictionary’s definition of 想像 has the following note:

> 现在一般写作“想象”。
>
> 注意 全国科学技术名词审定委员会和国家语言文字工作委员会已确定“想象”为推荐词形。

Which basically says that the word is usually written 想象 & that 想象 is the recommended “spelling.”

Comment: Worth noting is that 想象 is not even listed in the Taiwan MoE and the preferred form is 想像.

Answer (score 0):

想像 is like the more formal way of writing, but actually that is not a problem if talking to others casually, cuz others would understand the meaning using the words that are before and after (前文後語). But dont write this in formal writings or working environment, depending on who is reading, they might classify this is not the correct way of writing.